# sql - Creating records for each friend upon accepting friend request

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to sql and with postgres I'm trying to create a friend system using three tables. The users table, a friend request table, and a friends table which will hold the users relationships once accepted.

**Friend Request Table**

```
id
sender_id
recipient_id
```

**Friends Table**

```
id
user_id
friend_id
```

I am currently trying to write some sql so once a friend request is accepted the corresponding request record in the friend request table is deleted, then two records are inserted into the friends table for the friendship. One for each user. So AB and BA.

Ive tried queries along the lines, but i've had no luck.

```
WITH friend_request AS (
      DELETE FROM friend_requests
          WHERE id = friendrequestid
          RETURNING sender_id, recipient_id
         )
INSERT INTO user_friends (user_id, friend_id) 
    (SELECT sender_id, recipient_id FROM friend_request),
    (SELECT recipient_id, sender_id FROM friend_request);
```

Is there a correct way to do two inserts in the way I am attempting? Or am I approaching this in the wrong fashion?

Thank-you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `union all`:

```
WITH friend_request AS (
      DELETE FROM friend_requests
          WHERE id = friendrequestid
          RETURNING sender_id, recipient_id
     )
INSERT INTO user_friends (user_id, friend_id) 
    SELECT sender_id, recipient_id FROM friend_request
    UNION ALL
    SELECT recipient_id, sender_id FROM friend_request;
```

Personally, I would insert the new values before deleting them, but your approach is fine.

Comment: Thank-you this was what I was looking for.